# Property files Shoud not delete while Uninstalling a Java application

Tags: java, installation, uninstallation

I have developed a Java application and used InstallJammer,a tool for creating the installation file for product.. I have used two property file to support my application. I need to give exe versions of application time to time to my customers. I had a problem with these

When we uninstall an application , we should NOT to delete the property files. The New property files of an application should not overwrite old one.

Anyone know how to do this InstallJammer?
It would be very helpful for me

Comment: *"Anyone know how to do this InstallJammer?"*  I don't know, but I could tell you how to do it using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Does the app. have a GUI?

Comment: Yes Andrew, The application has GUI(A single window only).

Comment: JWS provides the `ExtensionInstallerService` to *"do any application set-up/pull-down that can not be handled by the standard JWS behaviour of caching the classes/resources at 1st launch, and clearing them at uninstall."*  Here is a [demo. of the service](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis).  In this case, at time of installation it would copy the properties files to a reproducible location (e.g. a sub-directory of `user.home`) but **only if they are not already there** (e.g. `!file.exists()`).

Comment: Sounds like you were using these property files to store configuration data. In which case you might be better off using the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) instead.